# HTTPS and HTTP CORS

Tags: ajax, http, https, request, cors

My questions is simple, but I cannot find an answer and I haven't got any resources to test it myself.

- Can I make HTTPS CORS request from one domain to another HTTPS domain?
- Can I make HTTP CORS request from one domain to another HTTPS domain?

I know that I can do HTTP CORS request from one domain to another HTTP domain, but I don't know if there is any difference when I use HTTPS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can do a CORS request from a HTTPS domain to another HTTPS domain.

The only difference is because HTTPS is a secure origin, you can only make call to secure origin, so not to HTTP, the browser will block it with a message like:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example2.com/endpoint'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Warning**: If you allow http requests to call your https webpage, it will be insecure because it means an attacker can force requests to your https webpage with the cookies of a victim and read the answer

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you, I can not make request from HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: @Raiper34 From an insecure http page you can make request to http and https. From a secure https page you can only make requests to https for security reasons (see mixed-content)

Comment: @Tom what if i want to make from https to https(2),but https(2) is some kind xyz.local domain, as it is not shown greenbar in browser,it is also blocked,is there another wayto do it ?

Comment: Isn't there any workarounds to allow the communication even if it is insecure?

Comment: @CharithJayasanka The workaround to call http from a secure context is to use a server proxy : you call your proxy using https, and that proxy, in the back-end call the http endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I managed to reverse proxy the local port in to HTTPS with lets encrypt and nginx. Now my issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Beware if you still need to support IE8/IE9 and are using XDomainRequest as it does not support cross-protocol requests. As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XDomainRequest#Security):

> The origin's security protocol must match that of the requested URL. (http to  http, https to https). If these do not match, the request will error "Access is Denied".