# console.log() not printing data to console on codepen.io

Tags: jquery, codepen

I'm trying to test whether an api call is successful but when I call the console.log() command in the function nothing is printed out in the console.  Please help.

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/').done(function(location){
        console.log(location.city);}
```

and ...

```
$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+latitude+'&lon='+longitude+'&unit=imperial&appid=5b98cbb01e7b431b5f074efdd59bb78b', function(data){
            apiData = data;
            console.log(apiData);}
```

Also when I try to overwrite the html in an element with jquery with "$('#element').html(variable)", nothing registers when I refresh the actual page. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the API call is succeeding? If it fails, the `.done()` function isn't called.

Comment: You're missing an ending parenthesis in the first one. Edit: And in the last one.

Comment: And also the second one.

Comment: Well, if you move the `console.log()` out of the AJAX done callback, do you see something? (My guess is you will). If you do, that means that your AJAX request was not successful.

Comment: Probably a [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066639/https-and-http-cors) error because CodePen is served from HTTPS and you're accessing HTTP.

Comment: @Barmar that's why I want to call the console.log() to check if it is successful.  I did copy the link to my browser and the URL for the callback does resolve.  Not sure why it's not registering when it's called in my code.

Comment: @Terry.  What can I do then to fix the AJAX request?

Comment: @nem035 - How do I change that?  Sorry for my ignorance :P

Comment: @BlackBat023 Change `http:` to `https:`. Or just leave out the protocol, and it will default to the same protocol as the calling page.

Comment: Yup, like Barmar said. Assuming `api.openweathermap` handles https. If not, there really isn't a way around it other than loading your project somewhere else or using something like JSONP.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/').done(function(location){
        console.log(location.city);})
```

and

```
$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+latitude+'&lon='+longitude+'&unit=imperial&appid=5b98cbb01e7b431b5f074efdd59bb78b', function(data){
            apiData = data;
            console.log(apiData);})
```

Ending parenthesis (of done() function and callback function) was missing in both cases.

Comment: The parenthesis are there ... I double checked, but still nothing :(.

Comment: Why aren't they in the code in the question? Post your actual code, how are we supposed to guess what's wrong if you've changed it?

Comment: It's quite a lot so I tried to tone it down to what I thought might be the problem.

Comment: @Barmar: Let me put it this way... my code is thus.  `code` var city;  $.getJSON('http://api-ip.com/json', function(position){ city = position.city; console.log(city); });`code` No response is given in the console.  Why is that?

Comment: There's something wrong here: var city; $.getJSON('api-ip.com/json';, function(position){ city = position.city; console.log(city); });You should not have a semicolon after the URL.

Comment: Also, the protocol is missing (it should be `http://api-ip.com/json` or https://), although that might just be SO removing it. Also, that URL just returns a 404 status code. 

Additionally, I also get a CORS error when I run the $.getJSON in my Chrome console:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api-ip.com/json?_=1495396659900. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access. So several things could go wrong here.

Comment: @cjs1978: Oh shoot sorry the ";" was a typo.  I also did put the protocol in, as you said, but still nothing.

Comment: But is `http://api-ip.com/json` the correct URL? Because I get a 404 there. And as mentioned, I also get a CORS error when I try to access the resource. Could it be that you actually mean `http://ip-api.com/json` ?

Comment: @cjs1978 - Yes sorry I mean "http://ip-api.com/json"  I'm really flunking out on this one aren't I :P.  I do appreciate your patience with me though.

Comment: I think it might be the http/https issue, then. Are you using codepen.io over https? It seems ip-api.com only works over http, and then you cannot make the $.getJSON, it will be blocked by the browser. See a nice description here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: Okay... I've now reverted to using secure codepen.io and my geolocation call successfully prints my latitude and longitude to the console.  I'm having an issue with my darksky.net api call now.  `$.getJSON("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[apiKey]/"+latitude+","+longitude, function(data){ console.log(data.currently.summery); });` prints nothing to the console. :(

Comment: You should read this: https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq#cross-origin. You cannot use Javascript (on the client side) to make direct calls to the API, since this would reveal your API key to the public. Instead, create a server side script (i.e. a PHP/Python/NodeJS script) to proxy the API call.

Comment: Adding to my comment above, just a quote from the link above: "Your API call includes your secret API key as part of the request. If you were to make API calls from client-facing code, anyone could extract and use your API key, which would result in a bill that you'd have to pay. We disable CORS to help keep your API secret key a secret.

To prevent API key abuse, you should set up a proxy server to make calls to our API behind the scenes. Then you can provide forecasts to your clients without exposing your API key."

Comment: @cjs1978 Good to know... thanks for that.  Still a bit rusty on PHP and NodeJS.  I started using apixu.com and that seems to be working for me.  But I'll keep your words in mind in the future.  Thank you to everyone your comments really did help. Hopefully I can now finish my project soon and hand it in and chalk this up to valuable experience.  Thanks again guys.