# How https can communicate with http

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, https, google-cloud-platform

I am newbie on Google cloud platform. I am facing issue with handshaking the https with http, I saw some articles where clealry mention that HTTPS can not handshake with HTTP.

I am describing my approach. I have 2 VM Instances of Windows server 2016.

1. 1st Instance will be of React Server. The Instance External IP is bind with domain name and also implemented the ssl certificate through nginx reverse proxy. Use 443 and add certificates on nginx.conf file.
   Assume that its external static IP will be: 35.35.35.36
2. 2nd Instance will be of Node server. Now for every API request React Server will call the Node server external ip with port.

Assume that This instance External IP is : 35.36.36.36.

Now for every call react call the api that is http://35.36.36.36:3000/ and this will generate the error that is

```
your page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
```

earlier case when frontend is on http then every thing is fine.

Should I also use new ssl certificate for my backend.

> Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Do not invent IP addresses for documentation, use the ones in RFC5737. Also, this is not a programming question, hence offtopic here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you **cannot** connect from HTTPS to HTTP, the former being secure and the latter being insecure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37068063/2873331

That was the sole motivation  for creating [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS):

> The principal motivation for HTTPS is authentication of the accessed
>   website and protection of the privacy and integrity of the exchanged
>   data while in transit. In HTTPS, the communication protocol is encrypted using Transport Layer Security (TLS), or formerly, its predecessor, Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

An HTTPS request is sent with a "code" which can be deciphered only by a properly configured HTTPS server. If anyone in between the sender and the recipient could open the request, they still could not understand it. Only the sender and the recipient, who know the "code," can decipher the message.

So either you convert your React server to be an HTTP server, which is not recommended or your configure your Node Server to accept HTTPS requests.

Hope this answers your question.