# How to make API written in nodejs run on https

Tags: node.js, api, ssl, nginx, svelte

I have my application with user and admin interface developed in [svelte js](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte) framework. They communicate each other using API written in nodejs. This entire application is deployed on AWS on one ec2 instance.

After installing ssl certificate, user and admin applications are running as https but API is not yet https and that is why user and admin applications don't communicate with each other.

Before installing ssl everything was working properly.

I have nginx running on aws server.

**User application** runs on port 80: `https://www.example.com`

**Admin application** runs on port 3000: `https://www.example.com:3000`

**API** is in nodejs: `http://www.example.com:8080`

Comment: Just a side note `https://` default port is 443 not 80 (80 is default for `http://`) so `https://www.example.com` is equal to `https://www.example.com:443` not `https://www.example.com:80`. But i think the problem is might be using a non secure API on a secure site. Maybe a lil snippet of your code would help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using nginx as a proxy and set the SSL certificate in this layer. Meaning: nginx will serve the SSL certificate and handle all incoming connections on port 80/443. You can then forward all incoming traffic to your local node.js applications accordingly:

Quick example:

```
upstream myUIProxy {
  # ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  keepalive 8;
}

upstream myAPIProxy {
  # ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  keepalive 8;
}

# the nginx server instance

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://myAPIProxy/;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myUIProxy/;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS apps can not communicate in default way with HTTP api (mixed content), also it is not secure and kind of bad practise. Look here: [HTTPS and HTTP CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066639/https-and-http-cors/37068063#37068063)

You can try to configure nginx proxy but I suggest simply to reconfigure your `Node.js` api server to use https :

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

More information can be found here :

https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/